# Removing specific item from file in isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a way to delete specific line in file that is in isolated storage, for example, I save a few lines of string in file, that is in isolated storage, and i want to delete specific string that i select in listbox(that lines of strings are read from isolated storage in listbox).
here is the code for writing:

```
StreamWriter writeFile;
            if (!store.DirectoryExists("SaveFolder"))
            {
                store.CreateDirectory("SaveFolder");
                writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("SaveFolder\\SavedFile.txt", FileMode.CreateNew, store));
            }
            else
            {
                writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("SaveFolder\\SavedFile.txt", FileMode.Append, store));
            }
            StringWriter str = new StringWriter();
            str.Write(urlHolder.Text);
            writeFile.WriteLine(str.ToString());
            writeFile.Close();


            urlHolder.Text = string.Empty;
```

and here is the code for reading:

```
 IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

            StreamReader readFile = null;
            try
            {
                readFile = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("SaveFolder\\SavedFile.txt", FileMode.Open, store));
                string fileText = readFile.ReadLine();

                while (fileText==readFile.ReadLine())
                {
                    bookmarkListBox.Items.Add(fileText);
                }

                readFile.Close();
            }

            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Need to create directory and the file first.");
            }
```

I cannot find anywhere nothing about removing something in specific file that is in isolated storage, so if anyone knows something, please reply, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The best method would be to write to the file one line at a time  and skip what you want to delete. If you have the file already on the SD card, write to another file, remove the original and replace it with the new version.

You have most of the code already done. Just write to the file one line at a time and skip the items you don't want to save.

```
writeFile.WriteLine(line);
```

Comment: I think that you didn't understand what i want to do.. I will try to explain more precise. So i have that lines of strings in that file, i want them there, but i also want ability to remove one of them, if i want, that i select of course. thank you for fast reply though...

Answer (score 2):

There aren't any built in capabilites for manipulating the contents of a file in IsolatedStorage in this way. The responsibility for working with the contents of the file is left up to the developer.

The easiest way to do what you're after is to read the entire contents of the original file, update it in memory and then rewrite the whole file, use FileMode `File.Create` to overwrite the existing file. (This will avoid any issues with the smaller contents being written over the larger earlier contents.)

Comment: yes, i thought that too, ok, i'll try...But how to "tell" to that file what string needs to be replaced, if you understand me..? thanks...

Comment: @user648539 If you know the string to remove, you could just get the whole file contents and then just call `.Replace()` on it, passing the string to remove as the first and String.Empty in the second parameter.